# MySQL - Custom order for every users

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

I want to allow my users to make a cart of fruit but also allowing the to order them the way they want.
I will try to explain my problem in the simplest way.

One table "user" contains the users with an auto-increment id field.

```
-----------------
| id | username |
-----------------
```

I have one table "fruits" witch contains fruits.

```
--------------
| id | fruit |
--------------
```

And I want to allow users to have a cart containing fruits, so I created the table "cart" :

```
---------------------------
| id | user_id | fruit_id |
---------------------------
```

So for example,

I have in "fruits" :

```
--------------
| 1 | Banana |
| 2 | Apple  |
| 3 | Orange |
--------------
```

If the user 1 want one of each I would have in "cart"

```
---------------------------
| id | user_id | fruit_id |
---------------------------
| 1  |    1    |     1    |
| 2  |    1    |     2    |
| 3  |    1    |     3    |
---------------------------
```

So if I execute :

```
SELECT fruit_id FROM cart WHERE user_id = 1;
```

I would have :

```
------------
| fruit_id |
------------
|     1    |
|     2    |
|     3    |   
------------
```

But I want to allow my user through a jQuery Sortable array to rearrange its cart so that MySQL will sort them for him.

I though of one solution that does not seems to be the best way ; Remake the "cart" table with the user_id and a string of fruit_id I will need to parse.

The second way was to delete the entries and re-enter them in the good order so that ordering by id would sort them, but I am not really happy with this situation too.

Do you know about a better/cleaner way to do so ?

Thank you very much for any insight/comment/knowledge.

Comment: Either add a new column to your CART table named sort_order. Or do the sorting in code with something like this: `SELECT fruit_id FROM cart WHERE user_id = 1 order by find_in_set(fruit_id, '3,1,2')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Similarly, result sets are *unordered* unless you use an `ORDER BY`.

You would seem to have two choices.  Add a column to the table, say `sort_order` as Juergen suggests in a comment.

Alternatively, do the ordering in the query:

```
SELECT fruit_id
FROM cart
WHERE user_id = 1
ORDER BY FIELD(fruit_id, 3, 2, 1);
```

This will sort in reverse order.  Note:  You can also use `FIND_IN_SET()`:

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(fruit_id, '3,2,1')
```